# Batch file to end process of one user

Tags: batch-file, process

We are several users on one server. I would like to write a bat file to end a process. But this process may run for other users and I want to kill only mine.

How do I do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
taskkill /fi "username eq %username%" /fi "imagename eq notepad.exe"
```

For current user, task `notepad.exe`